# match any decimals appearing immediately before a character in python

Tags: python, regex

I can't seem to find an example of this, but I doubt the regex is that sophisticated.  Is there a simple way of getting the immediately preceding digits of a certain character in Python?
For the character "A" and the string: 
"&#238A" 
It should return 238A

Comment: `A` is not a decimal character. Did you mean hexadecimal?

Comment: In that example, what is the "certain character"?  A?  The closing quote?

Comment: Do you care about limiting the match based on what precedes it too?  Like only numbers that come after &#?

Comment: @StevenDoggart   No, I'm just trying to figure out how 'immediately preceeding' is handled

Comment: @StevenDoggart  Edited my question to include the relevant character, A

Comment: Do you want to include the character in the result, or just the number that comes before it?

Comment: The regex pattern for that is exceedingly simple. It would just be \d+A

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for that kind of answer.

Comment: Do you want the character itself included in the result? If not you want to use positive lookahead: `\d+(?=A)`.

Comment: @pzp Do positive lookaheads lead to slow backtracking? Can't remember, I may be thinking more of lookbehinds. You could just put the digits in a group and extract the group like `(\d+)A`, that should avoid any potential backtracking.

Comment: @Marius Putting the digits in a capture group should also do the trick. :)

Comment: @pzp  Could you provide an example of that?

Comment: @DavidJ. For instance, for the character `'A'` and string `"&#238A"`, the pattern `\d+(?=A)` (or, as Marius suggested `(\d+)A`) would return `238` (note that the `A` is excluded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you intend to include the trailing character in the resulting match, the regex pattern to do that is very simple. For instance, if you want to capture any series of digits followed by a letter A, the pattern would be `\d+A`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python 3, try this.
Please refer to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information.

```
import re
char = "A" # the character you're searching for.
string = "BA &#238A 123A" # test string.
regex = "[0-9]+%s" %char # capturing digits([0-9]) which appear more than once(+) followed by a desired character "%s"%char
compiled_regex = re.compile(regex) # compile the regex
result = compiled_regex.findall(string)
print (result)
>>['238A', '123A']
```